# How to compute the ring structure of the cohomology of $RP^n/RP^k (0<k<n) $ with coefficient $Z/2Z$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $RP^n$ be the real projective space of dimension $n.$

By universal coefficient theorem I can compute $H^q(RP^n/RP^k,Z/2Z),$ but I have no idea how to determine the cup product.

Could somebody please show me how to do this? Besides can Poincaré duality be of use here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your space is not a topological manifold, I don't see Poincare duality being useful.  The way I would start computing the ring structure is to use the canonical map $\pi:\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n/\mathbb{R}P^k$ to pull back the calculation to a space where I know the cohomology ring.

Comment: These spaces are probably identifiable with other known spaces. E.g. $\mathbb{RP}^3/\mathbb{RP}^1$ is homotopy-equivalent to $S^3\vee S^2$, which gives the cohomology ring for free. But I don't know the general pattern off the top of my head.